# How to clear $localStorage

Tags: angularjs

In Angular I tried:

```
$localStorage.clear();
```

It got the error:

> $localStorage.clear is not a function

What is the correct calling convention to wipe out `$localStorage`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using [ngStorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage#delete-everything--demo) you can try $localStorage.$reset(); instead clear().

This method clear is the default HTML5 method, to use it you have to take off $, eg: localStorage.clear()

Answer (score 9):

As [the manual says](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage#delete-everything--demo),

```
$localStorage.$reset();
```

Comment: up voted b/c you answered the exact question. thanks!